# Linear independent or linear dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure to say if the following set is independent:

$$ \{1, \sin x, \cos x\}$$

I would say they are independent because after an analysis of the coefficients in the linear combination equal zero, the only setting possible are when they are all equal zero.

How should I prove this?

Comment: Well, if "*after an analysis of the coefficients in the linear combination equal zero, the only setting possible are when they are all equal zero*" means what it looks to mean, then you have proved it.

Comment: What is your field of coefficients? Because if, for instance, it's the field of elementary functions, then (under most reasonable definitions of elementary functions), they are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: write $$\alpha+\beta\sin(x)+\gamma\cos(x)=0$$
Setting $$x=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ you will get
$$\alpha+\beta=0$$
Setting $$x=\pi$$ then we get
$$\alpha-\gamma=0$$
and Setting $$x=0$$
then we have $$\alpha+\gamma=0$$
can you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

None of the $3$ vectors in the set is a linear combination of the other vectors. Therefore, the set is linear independent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x) = a + b\sin x + c \cos x$, which is infinitely continuously differentiable.

Linearly independence of the set in question is the same as showing that $f(x) \equiv 0$ if and only $a = b =c =0$.

Suppose that $f(x) \equiv 0$. Then derivatives of all orders are identically zero.

To see that $b$ and $c$ must be zero, note that $0 = f'(0) = b$ and $0 =f''(0) = -c$, but then these two conditions together with the assumption that imply that $a = 0$.

Hence, it follows that $f(x) = 0$ for all x implies that $a = b = c = 0$. This proves linearly independence of the set in question.